# Installing app in windows 11 without account

Tags: windows-11

Is there a way to install apps from the store in windows 11 without creating a microsoft account like in windows 10?
Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look around fro the same app from another source. Check any download in VirusTotal, though.

Answer (score 3):

No. You need a Microsoft Account.

With Windows 11 Home, you must use a Microsoft Account.

With Windows 11 Pro, you need to start with a Microsoft Account, but can change to Local once running.

For non-Business users, Microsoft Account are both Safe and overall more desirable.

So for what you want, use a Microsoft Account.

I do this for my Windows 10 Pro and Windows 11 Pro machines.

Comment: There are ways to install UWP applications without the Windows Store but I don't know how that would be possible without the appropriate edition of Windows.  Home and Professional are not the appropriate version.